# How to call an external method before executing annotated method and pass the arguments

Tags: java, annotations, aop, pojo

I am working on POJO project which is built using `Maven` into a standalone JAR. For the sake of maintainability I am looking into adding a way to use annotation based checks. In following code I have an annotated method, on the event of calling this method I would like that another method in another class to be executed and to be context aware so I can access arguments passed to the original method.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void someClassMethod(){

        ...

        get(new AnotherClass() {
            @CustomAnnotation
            public Object handle(ArgumentClass1 arg1, ArgumentClass2 arg2) {
                ...
            }
        });

        ...

    }
}
```

I am aware that this can be done with AspectJ, but I cannot find a real working examples of how to go about implementing such functionality. So I would like to ask for an example code, or links which point to working example.

Comment: Are you looking for a [pointcut on annotations](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/01/aspectj-pointcut-based-on-annotation-on.html)?

Comment: @John, maybe yes as I am not so much familiar with terminology. I looked at the page you pointed, but I could not see there any explanation to what is pointcut and how to exactly implement it. I am looking for a simplest way to do what I want - is to perform some checks before executing called method. To me it looks like annotations is the way to go here, but all tutorials I can find are targeted to people who already have pretty good knowledge and not to complete newbies (I am doing a lot of POJO, and never done AOP).

Answer (score 0):

I really cannot explain AOP basics to you. This is the wrong place to ask people for providing sample code without you being willing to at least read an AOP tutorial and grasp the basic concepts like aspect, joinpoint, pointcut and advice. I will even provide a fully functional sample for you in AspectJ (see below), but to what avail? Will you even understand it? What I am not going to provide is a Maven configuration because this would really be out of scope, even though I do know how to build AspectJ code with Maven. Feel free to use a search engine and learn, then come back with *specific* questions beyond "I am too lazy to learn, please do it for me".

**Argument classes according to your sample:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ArgumentClass1 {}
```

--

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ArgumentClass2 {}
```

**Sample annotation:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {}
```

**Abstract class according to your sample:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public abstract class AnotherClass {
    public abstract Object handle(ArgumentClass1 arg1, ArgumentClass2 arg2);
}
```

**Application class with some sample methods:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class SomeClass {
    public static void someClassMethod() {
        get(new AnotherClass() {
            @CustomAnnotation
            public Object handle(ArgumentClass1 arg1, ArgumentClass2 arg2) {
                return "dummy";
            }
        });
    }

    public static Object get(AnotherClass anotherClass) {
        return anotherClass.handle(new ArgumentClass1(), new ArgumentClass2());
    }

    private static void anotherClassMethod(String string, String string2) {}

    @CustomAnnotation
    private static void yetAnotherClassMethod(int i, int j) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someClassMethod();
        anotherClassMethod("foo", "bar");
        yetAnotherClassMethod(11, 22);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are some static methods, partly public/private, one of them annotated by `@CustomAnnotation` and the others not, one containing an anonymous class concretising the abstract class from above and also containing a method annotated by `@CustomAnnotation`. We should expect `yetAnotherClassMethod(int, int)` and `handle(ArgumentClass1, ArgumentClass2)` to be intercepted by an aspect because they carry our target annotation.

Last, but not least, ...

**Aspect intercepting methods carrying our custom annotation:**

```
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.CustomAnnotation;

public aspect AnnotatedMethodInterceptor {
    Object around() : execution(@CustomAnnotation * *(..)) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        for (Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs()) {
            System.out.println("  Checking argument " + arg);
        }
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

Instead of checking the arguments in my sample I am just looping over the array of arguments in order to print them. You can do anything you want here, though.

Now please go figure out what AOP and AspectJ syntax are all about. There are enough tutorials out there, just use your favourite search engine or start at http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php.

**Sample code console output:**

```
execution(Object de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.1.handle(ArgumentClass1, ArgumentClass2))
  Checking argument de.scrum_master.app.ArgumentClass1@1bdf2b92
  Checking argument de.scrum_master.app.ArgumentClass2@58a58c89
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.yetAnotherClassMethod(int, int))
  Checking argument 11
  Checking argument 22
```

Comment: While this answer may be useful, it is "a bit" cocky. Don't you think so yourself? As I stated in my question I'm coming from mostly POJO development. And I had no difficulty reading and learning maven and gradle ad there are lots of good tutorials and documentation. As about AOP - all I could find is tutorials not for someone who decided to touch it for the first time, but rather targeted to someone who already familiar with all the terminology and official docs for AspectJ just sucks. So excuse me, but the tone of this answer is super cocky. As for examples - thanks I'll try them.

Comment: You may skip the quotation marks, I admit to my answer being cocky. So what? My criticism is substantial and my answer constructive even so. It is just not true that there are no good AOP tutorials out there. If you read http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/starting.html you will see that it is targeted at absolute beginners coming from POJO development. I am a POJO developer myself, I never use Spring or EJB. I taught myself AspectJ just by reading the tutorials and other documentation material. I can also recommend the book "AspectJ in Action" by Ramnivas Laddad. Good luck!